# How edge directions should be in a graph database?

Tags: graph-theory, arangodb

I'm currently learning absolutely basics of ArangoDB - and graphs generally. I have played around with a simple graph where I have a channel, message, and a user. Like in a chat i.e. IRC.

However, it's not completely clear to me how the edge directions should be (where the arrows should point to).

So, if a user posts a message into a channel. So then basically message belongs to the channel and the message belongs to the user, right? And then the edges point to vertices like this, is this correct?

[image]